# Searching all documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have about 150,000 documents in my index. I've noticed that when I do a default search, which is limited to only returning 10 values, ES seems to return the first 10 values it finds, which aren't the best results.

I would like ElasticSearch to search all the data, sort by _score decending, and then return the top say 10 or 100 matches.

I can set the "size" parameter to a high value, but then I'd also be getting huge amounts of returned items. I just need the best 10 or so that exist in the database.

Comment: What criteria decides the score of document?

Comment: This is the actual behavior of elasticsearch, the first 10 are the best match among all documents. If you think they are not the best, it is a problem with your query. Can you provide your query and a document which is returned and another which is not ?

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel I think you are right, i did some more experimenting and it does seem like ES always returns the highest scoring data first, regardless of size.